# Добавление комментариев через ajax

Tags: ajax, yii

Привет! Требуется реализовать добавление комментариев через ajax, и как бы с этим все понятно, но также требуется чтобы при добавлении комментария он был виден всем участникам дискуссии находящимся на странице поста. Есть соображения как это реализовать ?

Comment: @barkovw если комментарий должен быть показан другим пользователям сразу после добавления, то не трудно представить как ляжет браузер, если кто-то зафлудит топик. Ну лис точно начнёт тормозить, если не упадёт...

Answer (score 1):

Так же как делают чаты `ajax` - через `ajax` сообщение, написанное вами, отправляется в базу,
и через `ajax` получаются сообщения в главном окне. Видели как в ВК изменятся время отправки запроса (1 минуту назад, 5 минут назад и т.д.). То же самое надо сделать и вам. Просто проверяйте, допустим, каждую секунду, базу данных на новые сообщения с помощью `ajax`

Comment: т.е. походу требуется обновлять страницу на клиенте через промежуток времени?

Comment: Мне кажется это будет сильно нагружать базу данных

Comment: Ваши методы реализации данного принципа зависят от того нагрузите ли вы базу данных. Если скажем закешировать ответ базы на 1 секунду. То каждому будет выдаваться кеш а не делаться запрос к базе. Кроме того можно же не выбирать все записи а ограничится только обновленными. Для этого вы должны аяксом послать запрос про последний ид у клиента и сравнить его с последним ид вставленным в базу если они разные то добавить те самые записи которых у клиента нету.

Answer (score 1):

Тут вроде норм описано, правда не для yii: [Простая AJAX система комментариев](http://habrasorium.ru/php/624-prostaya-ajax-sistema-kommentariev.html)

Comment: В данном примере добавленный комментарий отобразится только у вас в браузере, а требуется чтобы его увидели одновременно все кто смотрит страницу :)

Answer (score 1):

Node.js и socket.io вам помогут. Кстати, эти технологии использованы в ВК. Правда разворачивать отдельное node.jd приложение нравится не всем, так что можно поискать что-то похожее.

[Создаем чат на Node.js и Socket.IO](http://habrahabr.ru/post/127525/)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно посмотреть в сторону реализации технологии comet на базе php и js.